# Looping through gridview rows with a TemplateField when exporting to Excel using ClosedXML is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, closedxml

This is my code to loop through gridview rows when exporting the gridview to Excel using ClosedXML:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvPOlist.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvPOlist.Rows)
  {
    worksheet.Cell(i + 23, 3).Value = gvPOlist.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
    worksheet.Cell(i + 23, 4).Value = gvPOlist.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
    worksheet.Cell(i + 23, 8).Value = ((TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtReqDelDate")).Text;
   }
}
```

My output is

```
  Item Code       Description         Delivery Date
  code001         Item One            01/28/2016
  code004         Item Four           01/28/2016
```

The problem is the value of all my delivery date column captured the last row value of gridview. How can I get the correct value of my delivery date column based on its gridview row cell value?
Note: Delivery Date column is template field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two loops over the rows of your grid view. So you overwrite each cell multiple times. For the first two cells this works because you reference both the cell in the grid view and in the worksheet with `i`. For the third cell you write the grid view cell from every row to the same worksheet cell so only the last row survives.

To solve this remove one of the loops, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvPOlist.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cell(i + 23, 3).Value = gvPOlist.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
    worksheet.Cell(i + 23, 4).Value = gvPOlist.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
    worksheet.Cell(i + 23, 8).Value = ((TextBox)gvPOlist.Rows[i].FindControl("txtReqDelDate")).Text;
}
```